# How big of CC driver do I need?

Tags: led, driver

I am making a grow light. I have 72 3-watt LEDs on an aluminum sheet. 10 blue 62 red. They are wired in series. How big or how many watts LED driver do I need to power the light?
I have 100 watt CC LED driver, and five 50 watt CC LED drivers. But I can't get the 50 watt drivers to work correctly, they just keep making the lights pulsate.

[image: board and wiring]

[image: 50 watt driver]

[image: 100 watt driver]

Comment: All 72 are wired in series?

Comment: Do all the LEDs need the same current to work at full rated power?

Answer (score 1):

If *all* LEDs are 3 watts, then you need a driver that can supply (72 * 3) 216 watts.

The fact that you have different colors suggests you have diodes with different forward voltages, in which case you need to elaborate more on how your LEDs are wired — do you have a schematic?

**Edit:**

Based on your photos and information, you need to split the LEDs into groups such that the group total voltage does not exceed the voltage of the driver. With all of them wired in series, the total voltage you would need is around \$((10 \cdot 3.6V) + (62 \cdot 2.4V))\$ 184.8 volts<sup>1</sup>!

Your 100W driver is rated for 20-35 volts, according to the label in the photo. You need to split the LEDs up in such a way that the required voltage in in range for the driver. For example, with the 100W driver at 35V, you can drive at most \$(35V / 2.4V = 14.6)\$ 14 red LEDs in a series (providing 2.5V per LED). You then have to add additional series runs in parallel. Four such runs would be 56 LEDs. You would need a resistor in the fifth run to accommodate the last six LEDs. Since the driver is a constant current supply, at maximum output, it would adjust the voltage to maintain 3A, and each run (with equal voltage drops) would get \$(3A / 5)\$ 600 mA.

*Wait though, if the LEDs are 3 watts each, doesn't this exceed the 100W of the supply? Sixty-two 3W LEDs adds up to 186 watts!* Glad you asked...

The type of power LEDs that I'm basing my calculations on are *labeled* 3W, but if you study the datasheet, you'll note that the red LEDs actually are 1.8W while the blue LEDs are 2.7W. Also, the datasheet shows that they have a forward current of 0.7A, slightly more than is available with five sets as described above. If we were supplying them with 700mA, the wattage would add up to 111.6, slightly over the driver rating, but we're not. We're supplying 600mA, so this seems in line with the driver's capacity. You should use a meter to test and determine what your LEDs actually require, if you don't have the specs for them.

A single 50W driver can handle the ten blue LEDs but I don't know what voltage it supplies. Measure it and calculate. The drivers should have adjustments for current. You will need to limit the 50W driver for the blue LEDs to an appropriate amount.

---

<sup>1</sup> *Based on 3.6\$V_f\$ for 3W blue and 2.4\$V_f\$ for 3W red [Avago ASMT-Ax3x Power LEDs](http://www.avagotech.com/docs/AV02-2048EN).*

Comment: i could post a picture . would that help ?

Comment: Sure, more information is good.

Comment: @kckingbsc I updated the answer based on your photos.